# Definition of font weight

Tags: fonts, typography

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Weight) says this about font weight:

> The weight of a particular font is the thickness of the character outlines relative to their height.

Seeing this from the point of a mathematician, the outline is by definition a zero-width closed path. It also does not specify whose character's outline(s) is/are meant. If one looks at the stem of the ‘H’ in the [example graphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Helvetica_Neue_typeface_weights.svg), its ratio is ~0.30 (for weight 9), and ~0.04 for weight 2. Considering the entire glyph, its ratio is ~0.91 and ~0.77, respectively.

Given any glyph in such an image, how does one determine the thickness values 2…9? (or 100…900 in TrueType dimensions)

Answer (score 5):

"Weight" is *highly* subjective. The designer typically designs a 'regular weight', which would be '500' in the TTF units. After that, a *lighter* design gets a lower number and a *darker* design the higher number. The full range of `100..900` is to cater for everything from Ultra Light to Extra Black.

Thus, the value only 'means' something in relation to lighter and heavier designs of the same font. You cannot look at a single font and say "this must be a Bold version".